# SAMBA CUPS Samsung ML-191x two printers exact model both wont distinguish which is connected on which port

Tags: samba, printer, cups, centos6.2

I have installed a version of Cent0S 6.02 with SAMBA and CUPS 1.4.8 installed, I have two Samsung ML-191x that I need to install in the server so anyone can access the, both printer, if installed separately work very well everone can print to them but when I plug-in both and install them trough CUPS it's like it does not know where each printer is connected at and send's all jobs to the same printer, I then downloaded a utility configuration from Samsung to get all Samsung drivers, after messing around with the utility I found that there's a part where you can check the properties for the Samsung printers, theres a connection tab where you can specify where the printer is connected like ipp, lpd, socket, dev etc... now at first none was selected so I put one printer on /dev/mtd4 and the other on /dev/mtd5, but it does not work either and I do not know why are they mtd instead of /dev/usb/lp? Any hints? any help would be greatly apreciated as I have searched everywhere in the internet with not even one post that has the same problem as mine. Thanks I hope someone can help me.